# How to convert a WAV file to RAW Audio in C++?

Tags: c++, audio, wav, binary-data

I have searched for an answer to this question for several hours. I have already removed the 44 byte header, and have transferred the data using an ofstream. The input stereo WAV file is 16 bit PCM at a 44.1k Hz sample rate.

```
    int szm;
    char* buff = new char[szm];
    ifstream ssn(f_infile,ios::binary);

    ssn.seekg(0,ssn.end);
    szm = ssn.tellg();
    ssn.seekg(0,ssn.beg);
    ssn.read(buff,szm);
    ssn.close();

    ofstream sso(f_outfile,ios::binary);

    for(int i =0; i < szm; i++)
    {
            if(i > 44)
            {
                    word_w(file, buff[i],1);
                    word_w(file, 0-(buff[i]), 1);
            }
    }

    sso.close();
    file.close();
```

I got the size of the file, and read the data into a buffer. I know all a RAW data file is is binary data, and I thought this simple technique would work. However, I got mixed results.

This first one worked like a charm. It was the original sample I wanted to convert. It is a side by side comparison of the original WAV file [top] and the raw data [bottom] imported into Audacity at 44.1k Hz.

[image: sample1]

This next one distorted the right channel for some reason, and doubled the length of the file. It is also a stereo wave file, 16 bit PCM, 44.1k Hz sample rate.
[image]

This third one is completely distorted, and the length has increased even more than the previous one.

[image]

Why did it work on the first file, but not the other ones when they are all in the exact same file format (16 bit, 44.1k Hz sample rate, 2 channels)?

Comment: You have to get the size of the file before creating a buffer. Currently you're making an array with the variable `szm` that is not yet initialized, meaning that it contains some garbage. Then, I see some `file` variable and `word_w` function which are not declared in the provided code.

Comment: It may be worth checking some of those header fields to make sure you really do have the number of bits correct and maybe for the endienness of the sample data etc.

Comment: Your image suggests that the samples are being interpreted as `32bit float`.

Comment: Yeah turns out it was they were Big endian when I assumed they were little endian. Oh, and Audacity labels them as 32 bit float no matter the selection. Don't know why.